# Unable to generate a URL for the named route "regions.index" as such route does not exist

Tags: php, routes, laravel, laravel-4

I'm doing rest api with laravel 4 and I'm getting this error:

```
Unable to generate a URL for the named route "regions.index"
as such route does not exist.
```

My router:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api/v1'), function(){
   Route::get('regions', 'RegionsController@index');
   Route::get('regions/{id}', 'RegionsController@getOne');
   Route::get('regions/{id}/cities', 'RegionsController@getCities');
});
```

api/v1/regions and api/v1/regions/1/cities
are working fine

but api/v1/regions/1 is not working and thows exception, I really don't know why and can't find how to make it work.

Comment: Could you please either: Amend *what exactly it was you did* and mark your response as being correct. Or, if it is correct, mark The Shift Exchange's response as being correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have not named your routes.

You should change

```
Route::get('regions', 'RegionsController@index');
```

to

```
Route::get('regions', array('as'=>'regions.index', 'uses'=> 'RegionsController@index');
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank's for answer, I did solve it. I'm stupid and I call in controller route which I previously deleted. :(

I called in controller:

```
return View::make('regions.index', compact('regions'));
```

and regions.index was deleted